# How do I install the correct version of java for nextflow?

Tags: java, installation, version, nextflow

I am trying to start installation of nextflow with following command:

```
wget -qO- https://get.nextflow.io | bash
```

And i get this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jgit/api/errors/GitAPIException has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
```

If I run command `java -version` output will be the following:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

I also have tried to install different versions of java and set them as the default:

```
update-java-alternatives --list
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64

sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jaotc
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jar
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jarsigner
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for javac
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for javadoc
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for javap
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jcmd
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jconsole
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jdb
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jdeprscan
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jdeps
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jfr
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jhsdb
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jimage
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jinfo
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jlink
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jmap
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jmod
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jps
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jrunscript
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jshell
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jstack
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jstat
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jstatd
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for rmic
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for serialver
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jaotc
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jarsigner
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jar
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for javac
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for javadoc
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for javap
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jcmd
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jdb
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jdeprscan
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jdeps
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jfr
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jhsdb
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jimage
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jinfo
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jlink
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jmap
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jmod
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jps
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jrunscript
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jshell
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jstack
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jstatd
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for jstat
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for rmic
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for serialver
update-java-alternatives: jdk alternative does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jconsole
```

**What should I do to solve this problem? Do I need to completely uninstall java and reinstall it correctly? If so, how can i install it?**

Comment: Use https://sdkman.io/

Answer (score 0):

Nextflow just requires **Java 11 or later**. The output of `java -version` should look something like:

```
openjdk version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

If you're on Ubuntu, you can install OpenJDK 11 using:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
```

If you have other `java` alternatives installed, use `update-java-alternatives` (requires `java-common`) to set the version you want:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
```

If you see some 'no alternatives for' errors, usually you can just ignore them or treat them more like warnings since the `update-java-alternatives` should have properly reconfigured the alternatives to enable all of the required components for the version specified.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work :(
After installation and setting i still have java version "1.8.0_45"

Comment: Meanwhile the output of `sudo update-java-alternatives --list`  command is `java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: @Garkul Do you have another Java in your $PATH? What's the output of `which java`?

Comment: The output of `which java` is `/home/garkul/anaconda3/bin/java`

Comment: @Garkul So I think that should answer your question? Your Java (1.8.0_45) is not actually your system Java (1.11.0-openjdk-amd64). If you've installed Java into your base Conda environment, you may prefer to simply disable the automatic base environment activation using `conda config --set auto_activate_base false` and start a new terminal session. Otherwise, type `deactivate` to exit your virtual env.